# How do merge two branches with related changes into master?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

In GIT I have **2 BRANCHES and a MASTER**.

**BRANCH1** is **checked out from master** and it have **some commits** to be merged with master and **merging of BRANCH1** will take some time because of some testing reasons.

In that time I've to work on **another** Branch which is **BRANCH2**. So **BRANCH2 should have the commits of BRANCH1** as I'll do some changes upon **BRANCH1's commits**, then BRANCH2 will also be *merged* with **MASTER** after sometime when **BRANCH1 merged with the master (BRANCH1 will be merged first).**

1. checkout from BRANCH1 then do some commits then merge it master after BRANCH1 merged for sometime.
2. (OR) checkout from MASTER then rebase it with BRANCH1 then do some commits then merge it MASTER.

***So What is the best option I can do for working on BRANCH2 with BRANCH1 change then merging it with MASTER?***

Any suggestions are welcome and
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are ready to merge `branch2`, you should rebase it onto `branch1` (if `branch1` is not yet merge, or on top of `master` (if `branch1` was already merged)

That way:

- you resolve the conflicts locally, by replaying `branch2` commits on top of `master`
- the final merge will be a fast-forward (trivial) one.

That is, starting situation:

```
m--m--m
       \
        b1 --b1--b1--b1
              \
               b2--b2
```

Once you are ready, b1 might have evolved and been merged to master:

```
m--m--m--m--m---------------M--m--m (master)
       \                   /
        b1 --b1--b1--b1--b1         (branch1)
              \
               b2--b2--b2--b2       (branch2)
```

A [`rebase --onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt) will be enough:

```
git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base branch1 branch2) branch2

m--m--m--m--m---------------M--m--m--b2'--b2'--b2'--b2' (branch2)
       \                   /    (master)
        b1 --b1--b1--b1--b1         (branch1)
```

Then a `merge master` will be trivial